# Extraction Operator for pair

Tags: c++, standards, conditional-compilation, std-pair, extraction-operator

The standard provides [all the comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) and the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D) for `pair`. has the potential of an extraction operator been discussed?

For example:

```
template <typename _Ty1, typename _Ty2>
enable_if_t<decltype(declval<istream&>() >> declval<_Ty1&>(), true_type())::value && decltype(declval<istream&>() >> declval<_Ty2&>(), true_type())::value, istream&> operator >> (istream& lhs, pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>& rhs) {
    return lhs >> rhs.first >> rhs.second;
}
```

Obviously if this was used while `pair` contained types for which the extraction operator was not defined this would fail in the same way that comparing `pair`s of types that did not contain comparison operators would fail.

But just think of the joy of being able to stream in a `map`! Surely someone's proposed this?

Comment: If the first extraction succeeded but the second one failed, would you expect the first data to be put back into the stream? (Consider that the first element may be of user-defined type with user-defined stream extraction.)

Comment: It may have been discussed but it was probably decided if you want it it is easy enough to write your own.  Just like the containers do not have stream operators.

Comment: @KerrekSB No, I hadn't considered that :( I can see how this would thwart clearing flags and continuing to stream after extracting `pair`s in a loop :(